# Using PUT in ng.resource globally

Tags: angularjs, rest, angular-resource

In the ng docs, there is an example showing how to send the update requests using PUT. How to apply that globally in all resources?

```
app.factory('Notes', ['$resource', function($resource) {
return $resource('/notes/:id', null,
    {
        'update': { method:'PUT' }
    });
}]);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Because you have defined a service which can be included in any controller etc. where you just use Notes.update() to send your request to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You would inject the service into your application, the usual way

```
app.module('YourModule')
  .controller('MyCtrl',['Notes',MyCtrl]

function MyCtrl(Notes) {
  Notes.get({id:[id of the note you want to get]}, function(note) {
    $scope.note = note
    // edit the note however you want
  })
  // Then to update the note
  $scope.note.$update([callback function])
}
```